# No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, bean-validation

I have the following error

> javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could
>   be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating
>   type 'java.lang.Integer'. Check configuration for 'discounted'

My code is:

```
@Column(name= "discount_percentage")
@Size(min=0, max=90)
@Min(0)
@Max(90)
private Integer discountPercentage = 0;
```

I set it to 0 because i was getting a NullPointerException when loading my view.
And is Integer because i was reading in others question, and some people says that sometimes there are problems when using @Size with primitive types.

What should i do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI This is is NOT the JPA API. It is the Bean Validation API.

Comment: @Size works with String type only

Comment: @RishabhAgarwal also works for collections etc.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`@Size` is a Bean Validation annotation that validates that the associated `String` has a value whose `length` is bounded by the `minimum and maximum` values. And as your `exception` says it does not apply to `Integer` type.

Use: `@Range`

```
@Column(name= "discount_percentage")
@Range(min=0, max=90)
private Integer discountPercentage = 0;
```

Or you cloud also use only `@Max or @Min` and that will work too. For more info please take a look on [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/3.1/reference/en/html_single/) link.

Comment: Note that @Range is found in `org.hibernate.validator.constraints`, and not in `javax.validation.constraints`

Answer (score 14):

`@Size` is not used to validate min/max.

It's used to validate size of collections, length of strings, etc.

In this case you should use `@Min`, `@Max` instead.

Refer here for complete document: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html

Answer (score 0):

I have observed this pattern when, the **parameter** type does not match with validator. as here `List<String>` is not matiching `List<Long>`

Ex Validator:

```
public class MaxValidation implements ConstraintValidator<MaxParameterSize, List<String>> {
  ....
 }
```

Annotation Use :

```
    public Response abc(@NotNull @MaxParameterSize(10) List<Long> parcelIds { 
    ....
    }
```